# confirmation modal dialog in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get confirmation dialog with yes , no option instead of ok,cancel in javascript ?

Comment: web using such dialogs would be annoying :)

Comment: @mykhal not necessarily. They would be perfecly fine in a web application, for example, or when filling in a form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not using the native browser functions, no.

You would have to use a custom dialog class like [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: Be wary that this is known to cause accessibility issues in some cases for some browsers (eg screen readers)

Answer (score 2):

The default confirmation box is baked into browsers. But you can make use of modal dialogs with the little help of plugins like [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) or [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#dialog).

Answer (score 1):

Not with the native confirm function. You would have to use a custom dialog. Fortunately, there are a lot of good ones available, check out jQuery and it's plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                    .html('<div><h6>Are you sure?</h6></div>')
                    .dialog({
                        modal: true, title: 'Delete message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                        width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                        buttons: {
                            Yes: function () {
                                // $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');                                
                                // $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            No: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });
```

for [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nM3Zc/) :