# how to develop yes no confirmation using jquery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

How to develop confirmation dialog with yes no button using jquery or any other method ?
I need that confirmation when I click on submit button.

Comment: Are you sure want an "Are you really sure!" button.

Comment: Duplicate from the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165559/confirmation-model-dialog-in-javascript/3165601#3165601.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the native browser confirm dialog.

```
if(confirm("Are you sure?"))
{
    //Ok button pressed...
}
else
{
    //Cancel button pressed...
}
```

Comment: return true or false depending on if you want the overlaying objects action to go or not go, for instance a link that has been clicked.

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution, it is working for me.

```
     $.alerts.okButton = ' Yes ';
     $.alerts.cancelButton = ' No ';                  
     jConfirm('Are you sure??',  '', function(r) {
       if (r == true) {                    
          //Ok button pressed...
       }  
     });
```

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeErrorL Cannot set property 'okButton' of undefined'

Comment: Did you configure jQuery properly?!!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you both a native JS and jQuery version:

```
function confirm_action( strMessage ) {
    strMessage = (typeof strMessage !== 'undefined') ? strMessage : 'Are you sure you want to do this?';
    return !!confirm( strMessage );
}

$.fn.confirm_action = function ( strMessage ) {
    $(this).click( function(){
        return confirm_action( strMessage );
    });
};
```

Two different ways to use it.  These work on links or Submit inputs.

JavaScript:

```
<input type="submit" formaction="process.php" onclick="return confirm_action();" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#mybutton').confirm_action();
```

Note that in either version you can customize the confirmation message by passing a string parameter.

Comment: This does not give Yes/No.