# Javascript alert button with Ok and Submit Anyway button on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

I am doing validation of fields using javascript and i need "Submit Anyway" button on Alert box if user wants to continue without filling the fields.

Comment: Please add code or more detail.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change `Alert Box button` text, however you can use `Confirm Box` like this:

```
var result = confirm("Submit Anyway");
if (result == true) {
    console.log('Yes');
}
else {
    console.log('No')
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/9eJDj/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery Confirm](http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/) and do something like :

```
valueOne = $("#textboxOne").val();
valueTwo = $("#textboxTwo").val();

if(valueOne == null && valueTwo == null) {
    $(".confirm").confirm();
}
```

Or, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166036/how-to-develop-yes-no-confirmation-using-jquery), use the native browser confirm dialog and do:

```
if(confirm("Are you sure?"))
{
    //Ok button pressed...
}
else
{
    //Cancel button pressed...
}
```