# Yes or No confirm box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, alerts, jconfirm

I want yes/No alerts using jQuery, instead of ok/Cancel button:

```
jQuery.alerts.okButton = 'Yes';
jQuery.alerts.cancelButton = 'No';                  
jConfirm('Are you sure??',  '', function(r) {
    if (r == true) {                    
        //Ok button pressed...
    }  
}
```

Any other alternatives?

Comment: Dupe, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166036/how-to-develop-yes-no-confirmation-using-jquery

Comment: Have a look at the **jQuery UI**: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165559/confirmation-model-dialog-in-javascript/3165601#3165601

Comment: this posted code works? what shall i replace 'jQuery' with? its not working for me...i guess i shall use $ but how? whats the syntax

Comment: $.alerts.okButton = ' Yes ';
     $.alerts.cancelButton = ' No ';                  
       jConfirm('Are you sure??',  '', function(r) {
         if (r == true) {                    
            //Ok button pressed...
         }  
       }

Comment: Another JQuery Dialog solution more like a confirm() function which returns: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18474005/1876355 Hope this helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519861/yes-or-no-confirm-box-using-jquery/10753619#10753619

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```js
ConfirmDialog('Are you sure');

function ConfirmDialog(message) {
  $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html('<div><h6>' + message + '?</h6></div>')
    .dialog({
      modal: true,
      title: 'Delete message',
      zIndex: 10000,
      autoOpen: true,
      width: 'auto',
      resizable: false,
      buttons: {
        Yes: function() {
          // $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');                                
          // $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

          $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>Yes</i></h1>');

          $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        No: function() {
          $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>No</i></h1>');

          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      },
      close: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: is this jquery-ui or plain old jquery? I don't see .dialog() anywhere on jQuery's documentaiton.

Comment: u need to include jquery and jquery ui script in your page.

Comment: @Thulasiram how can I add the plugin in `yii2` framework ?

Answer (score 144):

The alert method blocks execution until the user closes it:

use the confirm function:

```
if (confirm('Some message')) {
    alert('Thanks for confirming');
} else {
    alert('Why did you press cancel? You should have confirmed');
}
```

Comment: `confirm` is "OK CANCEL" though, not "YES NO".

Answer (score 75):

I've used these codes:

HTML:

```
<a id="delete-button">Delete</a>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$("#delete-button").click(function(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")){
        $("#delete-button").attr("href", "query.php?ACTION=delete&ID='1'");
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

These codes works for me, but I'm not really sure if this is proper. What do you think?

Comment: More shorter `return confirm("Are you sure you want to return this meter?")` ))

Answer (score 28):

Have a look at this jQuery plugin: [jquery.confirm](http://myclabs.github.com/jquery.confirm/).

```
<a href="home" class="confirm">Go to home</a>
```

and then:

```
$(".confirm").confirm();
```

This will show a confirmation popup before proceeding to following the link.

There's a demo here: http://myclabs.github.com/jquery.confirm/

Answer (score 13):

All the example I've seen aren't reusable for different "yes/no" type questions. I was looking for something that would allow me to specify a callback so I could call for any situation.

The following is working well for me:

```
$.extend({ confirm: function (title, message, yesText, yesCallback) {
    $("<div></div>").dialog( {
        buttons: [{
            text: yesText,
            click: function() {
                yesCallback();
                $( this ).remove();
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $( this ).remove();
            }
        }
        ],
        close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
        resizable: false,
        title: title,
        modal: true
    }).text(message).parent().addClass("alert");
}
});
```

I then call it like this:

```
var deleteOk = function() {
    uploadFile.del(fileid, function() {alert("Deleted")})
};

$.confirm(
    "CONFIRM", //title
    "Delete " + filename + "?", //message
    "Delete", //button text
    deleteOk //"yes" callback
);
```

Answer (score 6):

I had trouble getting the answer back from the dialog box but eventually came up with a solution by combining the answer from this other question [display-yes-and-no-buttons-instead-of-ok-and-cancel-in-confirm-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445946/display-yes-and-no-buttons-instead-of-ok-and-cancel-in-confirm-box) with part of the code from the modal-confirmation dialog

This is what was suggested for the other question:

Create your own confirm box:

```
<div id="confirmBox">
    <div class="message"></div>
    <span class="yes">Yes</span>
    <span class="no">No</span>
</div>
```

Create your own `confirm()` method:

```
function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn)
{
    var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
    confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
    confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function()
    {
        confirmBox.hide();
    });
    confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
    confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
    confirmBox.show();
}
```

Call it by your code:

```
doConfirm("Are you sure?", function yes()
{
    form.submit();
}, function no()
{
    // do nothing
});
```

**MY CHANGES**
I have tweaked the above so that instead of calling `confirmBox.show()`  I used `confirmBox.dialog({...})`  like this

```
confirmBox.dialog
    ({
      autoOpen: true,
      modal: true,
      buttons:
        {
          'Yes': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            $(this).find(".yes").click();
          },
          'No': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            $(this).find(".no").click();
          }
        }
    });
```

The other change I made was to create the confirmBox div within the doConfirm function, like ThulasiRam did in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try This... It's very simple just use confirm dialog box for alert with YES|NO.

if(confirm("Do you want to upgrade?")){
Your code
}

Answer (score 0):

I needed to apply a translation to the Ok and Cancel buttons.  I modified the code to except dynamic text (calls my translation function)

---

```js
$.extend({
    confirm: function(message, title, okAction) {
        $("<div></div>").dialog({
            // Remove the closing 'X' from the dialog
            open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
            width: 500,
            buttons: [{
                text: localizationInstance.translate("Ok"),
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    okAction();
                }
            },
                {
                text: localizationInstance.translate("Cancel"),
                click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }],
            close: function(event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
            resizable: false,
            title: title,
            modal: true
        }).text(message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You can reuse your confirm:

```
    function doConfirm(body, $_nombrefuncion)
    {   var param = undefined;
        var $confirm = $("<div id='confirm' class='hide'></div>").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                Yes: function() {
                param = true;
                $_nombrefuncion(param);
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
                No: function() {
                param = false;
                $_nombrefuncion(param);
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
                                    }
        });
        $confirm.html("<h3>"+body+"<h3>");
        $confirm.dialog('open');                                     
    };

// for this form just u must change or create a new function for to reuse the confirm
    function resultadoconfirmresetVTyBFD(param){
        $fecha = $("#asigfecha").val();
        if(param ==true){
              // DO THE CONFIRM
        }
    }

//Now just u must call the function doConfirm
    doConfirm('body message',resultadoconfirmresetVTyBFD);
```

Comment: Please, use correct English and avoid abbreviations like "u". Also, it is better if you can explain a little bit your code to illustrate and educate the OP, and why you think your answer is better than any of the previously posted.