# can you alter the button titles on javascript confirm?

Tags: javascript, confirm

Just wondering if there was an easy way to change the 'yes', 'cancel' titles on the confirm box window in javascript? Just seems a bit limiting if not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Yes, No, Cancel is a browser's basic feature, which cannot be modified. But you can make alternates like: [Yes or No confirm box using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519861/yes-or-no-confirm-box-using-jquery)