# jquery dialog too many buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

here is my code with jquery ui:

```
jQuery("#nodeliverydate").dialog({
    resizable:false,
    draggable:false,
    modal:false,
    buttons:[{text:"Close",click:function(){jQuery(this).dialog("close");}}]
});
```

It is a very simple code that using `jquery dialog` as an alert box. I defined one button to close the dialog. However, it runs in a very odd way that the dialog will contain many buttons, and the text on the buttons are all function names such as `"each","all","clone","select","size", etc`. And after I close it, if the dialog shows again, it will be normal. Does anyone have any idea about why this happens?

Comment: I am not seeing that. http://jsfiddle.net/C9c8a/

Comment: Let me break it down for you... http://jsfiddle.net/C9c8a/1/ Check out the official documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Comment: Need input, provide more information as this does not appear to be all the context of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery("#nodeliverydate").dialog({
                    modal: true, title: 'Delete msg', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                    width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                    buttons: {
                        Yes: function () {
                            // $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');                                
                            // $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();

                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        No: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
```

This work pretty well: [Yes or No confirm box using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519861/yes-or-no-confirm-box-using-jquery)

Comment: This works for me. Thank you. But I still don't know why my code doesn't work. I used my code many times before but none of them had that kind of problem. Any ideas why?