# how use a popup box (alert) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i'am new in `ASP.net MVC`

I want to upper a popup box when i click on an `Html` button , and when i confirm this `Alert` i want to be redirected to a specificed `Action` in my controller.

Any ideas please.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Your question is overly broad for this site. You should read the [help]

Comment: Do you want a nice pretty dialog, with custom HTML and CSS or do you want to capture the result of a javascript `alert("message")`

Comment: yes Nate, that's exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `jQuery`, you'll need to understand `Dialog` and javascript `callback` methods.

Example of a user giving a text response:
http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-alert-box/

Example of a dialog box with Yes and No buttons:
[Yes or No confirm box using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519861/yes-or-no-confirm-box-using-jquery)

To invoke an action on a controller you could do this, javascript:

```
window.location.href = "/ControllerName/DoIt?id=12345&msg=hello";
```

or

```
$.ajax( {url:"/ControllerName/DoIt",
        data: "id=12345&msg=hello",
        success: function (data){
        }
});
```

Your controller method would look like this:

```
public ActionResult DoIt(int id, string msg )
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: yes i totaly agree with you, but my problem is how to send an Action from the popup to the Controller (if i click on yes for exemple )