# Detect button "No" from Confirm jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

i'm have problem with confirm Jquery..

if

```
confirm("Confirm yes or no", function () {
        alert('button yes clicked');
    });
```

this mean, if i click button "Yes"  this show alert("button yes clicked") ,
but how is i'm click button "No " ? i'm want to run alert (button No clicked)

thanks.. sorry for my english

Comment: This question has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519861/yes-or-no-confirm-box-using-jquery

Comment: @Simon it doesn't look like he's using jConfirm.

Answer (score 1):

This is not jquery, this is native javascript. `confirm` returns a boolean. Simply set the confirm to a variable, and check if there is a response or not.

```
var response = confirm("Confirm yes or no");
if (response) console.log("Yes");
else console.log("No");
```