# Redirect on dialog button click - JQuery UI

Tags: jquery

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){
  $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
        .html('<div> Select </div>')
        .dialog({
            modal: true, title: 'Select', zIndex: 10000,autoOpen:true,
            width: 'auto', 
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
      modal: true,
      hide: { effect: "clip", duration: 1000 },
            buttons: {
             A: function () {
              window.location.href="xyz.php?param=A";
                },
                B: function () {
                  window.location.href="xyz.php?param=B";
                }
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
             
            }
        });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<div class="btn">Click</div>
```

I am trying to redirect when there is a button clicked. Current Implementation redirects to `myHomePage/0 or myHomePage/1`. None of my params are set and redirecting php also not working.

What is wrong in this? Please let me know.

Comment: Have you runned the snippet that you posted?

Comment: You have a syntax error, did you see that? You're missing a `,`, after `autoOpen:true`

Comment: May I Know the reason for downvote. I have added correct plug in to work it.

Answer (score 1):

Plz try this code

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
   var redirectId = $(this).attr('redirectId');
   window.location.href = "http://ursite.com/"+redirectId;
 });
```

in html

```
<div redirectId="1" class="btn">Click</div>
```

Comment: I know it. I have to use dialog. User has to select A or B. Then I have to redirect it.

Comment: can you say the plug-in you have used

Comment: jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js and jquery/jquery-ui.min.css

Comment: hey plz check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519861/yes-or-no-confirm-box-using-jquery

Comment: I am using similar thing. My case is redirection. My question itself redirection is not working

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like this:

**jQuery**:

```
$("div.btn").click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    if(typeof href !== typeof undefined && href !== false){
        window.location.href = href;
    }
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div href="newlocation.php" class="btn">Click</div>
```

It will work on all `div`'s with a class of `btn`, that contain the `href` attribute!

Comment: I know it. I have to use dialog. User has to select A or B. Then I have to redirect it.