# Jquery confirm() in an attached event handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-confirm

I have delete buttons in a list that is populated by an AJAX call. These buttons are suppose to trigger a confirm dialog, but I cannot get the confirm dialog to display when called in this click event handler. Do I need a separate handler? I hope someone can direct me towards a solution.

```
$('#list').on('click', '.btnRemoveNote', function () {                   
                $(this).confirm({
                    msg: 'Do you really want to remove this?'
                });                      
            });
```

this is how the list is generated

```
function funcLoadList(racodeID) {
    if (racodeID == null || racodeID == '') { console.log('bypassing list load, racodeid was null'); return; }
    console.log("Load List function initiated for " + racodeID);
    $('.table-row').remove();
    var url = '<%= Url.Action("MemberGetNoteList", "AccessCodes") %>';
    var downloadUrl = '<%= Url.Action("MemberDownloadNoteDocument", "AccessCodes") %>';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { RacodeID: racodeID },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#listStatus').text('Updating List...');
        },
        complete: function () {
            //   $('#fileStatus').text('Request complete...');
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        type: 'POST',
        error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            $('#listStatus').text('Sorry, there was a connection error: ' + xhr.status + '\n Please try again later.');
            console.log('There was a error: ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.responseText);
            return errorThrown;
        }
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        $('#list').show();
        $('.list-no-note').remove();

        if (data == '') {
            $('#list').hide();
            $('#listContainer').append('<div class="list-no-note">There are no notes for this member. Use the "Add Member Note/Document" area to add your first note.</div>');
            $('.exportNotesLink').hide();
        }
        else {


            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var followRequired = false;
                var followUpBtn = '';
                var followUpInfo = '';
                var commentArea = '';

                if (item.followUpEmailSentOn != null)
                    followUpInfo = new Date(parseInt(item.followUpEmailSentOn.substr(6)));

                var fulfilledBtn = '<span class="fulfill unfulfilled" >Fulfilled</span>';
                item.dateCreated = new Date(parseInt(item.dateCreated.substr(6)));

                if (item.followUpDate != null) {
                    followRequired = true;
                    item.followUpDate = new Date(parseInt(item.followUpDate.substr(6)));

                } else { item.followUpDate = "N/A"; }

                if (item.isFulfilled) {
                    fulfilledBtn = '<span class="fulfill fulfilled" >Fulfilled</span>';
                } else {
                    fulfilledBtn = '<span class="fulfill unfulfilled" >UnFulfilled</span>';
                }

                if (!item.followUpEmailSent && item.followUpDate != 'N/A' && !item.isFollowedUp) {
                    followUpBtn = '<img src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/Icons/followup_icon.png") %>" class="followUpBtn" title="A followup is scheduled for ' + item.followUpDate + '"  />';
                }

                if (item.followUpEmailSent && item.followUpDate != 'N/A' && item.followUpEmailSentOn != null) {
                    followUpInfo = '<img src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/Icons/checkmark.png") %>" height="20px" style="vertical-align:middle"/><span style="color:green">A Follow-up email was sent on ' + followUpInfo + ' to ' + item.followUpEmail + '</span>';

                }

                if (item.comment != null && item.comment != '') {
                    commentArea = '<b>Comment:</b><span class="noteComment" > ' + item.comment + '</span><br /><br />';
                }
                //console.log("inside loop...");
                var table;
                var shortFileName;
                var iconFile = '';
                var followupDate = '';

                if (item.fileName != '' && item.fileName != null && item.fileName.length > 25)
                    shortFileName = jQuery.trim(item.fileName).substring(0, 25).trim(this) + "...";
                else
                    shortFileName = item.fileName;

                if (shortFileName != '' && shortFileName != null) {
                    iconFile = '<img src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/Icons/text_icon.png") %>" height="20px" title="Download this document" class="masterTooltip" style="vertical-align:middle"/>';
                }

                if (item.followUpDate == null)
                    followupDate = 'N/A';
                else
                    followupDate = item.followUpDate;


                var tr = (
                '<tr style="border-top:1px solid gray" class="table-row">' +
                '<td class = "' + item.ID + '"> ' + fulfilledBtn + '</td>' +
                '<td>&nbsp;</td>' +
                '<td><span class="NoteDesc">' + item.description + '</span></td>' +
                '<td>' + item.requestTakenBy + '</td>' +
                '<td align="right"><a class="btnRemoveNote"><img class="' + item.ID + '" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/Images/Icons/delete-icon.png") %>" /></a></td>' +
                '<td>&nbsp;</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr class="table-row">' +
                '<td colspan = "2" >' + followUpBtn + '</td>' +
                '<td colspan="3" >' + commentArea + iconFile + '<a class="downloadUserFile"><span class="' + item.ID + '">' + shortFileName + '</span></a></td>' +
                '<td></td>' +
                '</tr><tr class="table-row">' +
                '<td colspan="6" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:20px;padding-bottom:10px;"><i><b>Follow-up Date:</b> ' + item.followUpDate + '</i></td></tr>' +
                 '</tr><tr class="table-row">' +
                '<td colspan="6" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:20px;padding-bottom:10px;">' + followUpInfo + '</td></tr>' +
                 '<script>$(".btnRemoveNote").confirm({msg: "Do you really want to remove this?  "});<\/script>'
                    );

                $('#list').append(tr);

            });
        }
    });

    $('#listStatus').text('');
    console.log("Load List function complete...");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Unless you are using a plugin, there is no jQuery confirm method. If you are using a plugin the plugin docs would show you how to display it. Check console for errors

Comment: Besides what's in the first comment, please post the way you are creating the buttons, this could be an event binding problem after your ajax call check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a JavaScript confirm.

```
$('#list').on('click', '.btnRemoveNote',
  function () {                   
    confirm('Do you really want to remove this?');
  }                    
);
```

I think there is no $(this).confirm() in JQuery, just .dialog which has more parameters.  Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519861/yes-or-no-confirm-box-using-jquery). You could use that if you want.

Comment: I am using the jquery.confirm.js plugin.  I would like to use it here as we use this plugin in a few other areas within the application.  There are no errors generated, the record is simply removed without any confirmation.